# Write Com object in Java

Tags: java, vba, excel, com

I need to write a Com object to use it in VBA (excel) using Java. I already wrote it in C# using ComVisible, it works good. But now I need to rewrite it in Java. I have found a lot of information about how to use Com objects in Java, but I could not able to find enough information to write Com objects by myself in Java (like ComVisible assembly in net). Maybe someone would help me on this.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to go via C++ - you can use it to implement the COM interface, and then use JNI to call Java. Doesn't sound much fun though!

Comment: Hm.. Yes, it more easy in C#

Comment: A very long time ago (>10 years) this was easy - but Microsoft and Sun (as they were then) had a big falling out, and ever since then neither side has had much interest in making it work.

Comment: Ok. As I read about JNI its realy hard way for my task becouse I have a lot of complex types (classes with a lot of methods and fields in C# application).. I am upset :(

Comment: you can write your ActiveX interface object in C# and use a simple application specific C#<->Java protocol based e.g. on files and command line processes or TCP sockets or... This way you'd also get the work done. Learning C++ or JNI is too heavy if you don't need some extra perfect performance. Using COM object for communications from Excel to outside is just a tool. What is your goal? What will the Java application provide? What kind of messages will flow? ..Can you provide [UML sequence diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-examples.html)?

Comment: In few words application gets data from web service in real time. Inside excel VB application on some intervals (2-5 seconds) needs to call java application to get data from remote service. To use java is not my idea. It is a customer wish. In C# i have writing a prototype. So I would try to talk to customer to use C#. At this days i have read a lot of JIN and so my opinion - it's terrible to write com using it)

Comment: I think the customer is lost in the "Java vs. ActiveX" debate of 15 years ago. :) It doesn't ally in your case, as far as I can see; the component is not user facing. The choice of implementation language for those is not normally left to the customer. By the way, calling most Web services straight from VBA is totally possible; read up on WinHTTP and MSXML.

Answer (score 0):

`I already wrote it in C# using ComVisible, it works good. But now I need to rewrite it in Java.`

This sounds like you have already solved the problem - why do you need a Java version.

If you really need the C# code to talk to Java (and vice-versa), you might have better luck with [JNI4Net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/), which appears to be a free version of [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/jnbpro.htm).

Sorry to give so many links, but I can't make any better recommendations without understanding why you need a Java version.

EDIT:

Mono apparently added Java support (see [Mono Java](http://www.mono-project.com/Java)).  FYI Mono is not official C#, and has rewritten the C# CLR virtual machine, but its probably as close as you will get to recompiling Java with the CLR VM.

Comment: please read comments above. It not my idea to rewrite it in Java. Now I am talking to customer to leave solution in .net C#.

Comment: A little more information would really help.  If I'm reading the original post correctly you are using COM to interface with MS Excel.  Excel only runs on a windows machine, so I'm still not clear on why anyone would want a Java version.

Comment: No. My application exports some classes for using it as Com-objects. Its not only excel, but all Ms Office applications using VBA. Or something else.